# Regex to not consider a phrase in a string

Tags: regex, tcl

The background is as follows:

- I m working on converting URL (with or without protocol and `www`) into
  clickable links.
- I have the regex working for URLs with `http`, `https`, `ftp`, `file`, `www` and some combination of `http/https` with `www`.
- I also have the regex working for URLs with just `www` and no protocol.

However, I m unable to figure out a working one for finding URLs with no protocol and no server name (`www`).

I tried the following in (http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

```
 ([^www\.|http\:// ][a-zA-Z0-9\.]+)((?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4})([\/a-zA-Z0-9]+)([\?][a-zA-Z0-9]+)?
```

But that seems to work only that website and not on my application. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: regex come in many flavors. Describe how you intend to use it (Perl, php, Javascript, …) and give an example of a couple of things that you want to match / not match. Is it basically "find a valid URL in a piece of text, even if it doesn't have `http://` or `www` in it"?

Comment: Hi @floris - I intend to use it for an application written in Tcl. It is for work. For example, if a user types in "I found this in example.com/ex?a_id=0011", then the mentioned URL (without protocol or server name) should be converted to a link. I need help with the regex to identify the URL. I have the working regex for other cases like - http://www.google.com (also https), http://google.com (also https), www.google.com, ftp://xxx.xx.something, file://something etc. Thanks for your help!

Comment: How "good" does this need to be? When you google "regex URL validation" you find that a "good" one can be 7k in size (!!!). Are we looking for the 99% solution? Could you post 20 URLs that should be matched in a piece of text - it would give a more reasonable target to aim for (and presumably you have some idea of the kinds of links you encounter since this is a real world problem)

Comment: @Floris - Let's say we are looking at a decent solution. Most often than not, the users of our system are going to copy paste the URLs from elsewhere (even if they intend on specifying URLs) - so that will have https or http or www and it will be resolved. The regex I need should handle URLs if the users manually type in their URL (examples are **gojira.dev.example.com/browse/ABC-12221**, **gopro.com/cameras/hd-hero3-white-edition#what-s-included**, **phonearena.com/phones/Nokia-Asha-500_id8190**. Please note that these are just examples, but we are looking to resolve something similar.Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

OK, you're probably not going to like this answer much - but then maybe you will? I have a regular expression (adapted from ) that seems to find URLs in text.  You can see a demo [on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/vV2nC5) .

The actual expression is very very long - this is because it's got "every legal TLD (top level domain) in it, which is a good start for finding "good" URLs.  Here it is

```
((?:(?:http|ftp|https):\/{2}){0,1}(?:(?:[0-9a-z_-]+\.)+(?:aero|asia|biz|cat|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|jobs|mil|mobi|museum|name|net|org|pro|tel|travel|ac|ad|ae|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|as|at|au|aw|ax|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|cr|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|ee|eg|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gg|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|im|in|io|iq|ir|is|it|je|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mk|ml|mn|mn|mo|mp|mr|ms|mt|mu|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|nc|ne|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nu|nz|nom|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ra|rs|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tl|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw|arpa)(?::[0-9]+)?(?:(?:\/(?:[~0-9a-zA-Z\#\+\%@\.\/_-]+))?(?:\?[0-9a-zA-Z\+\%@\/&\[\];=_-]+)?)?))
```

As you can see the vast majority of the expression is taken up making sure that the TLD is one of the many legal ones (270 alternatives. I didn't know there were this many until I stumbled on http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex where I found the seeds of this expression).

Changes I made to the expression I found at the link above - mostly I just made all the groups (except the outer one) non-capturing so there is just a single "match". In the sample I posted I showed that a "good" protocol definition (like `http://`) will be included in the capture, while a "bad" one (like `http:/`) will be ignored - however the following URL will still be captured.  I also showed that adding punctuation right after the expression (tested with `;` and `!`) doesn't phase the expression: it captures "up to that point" and not beyond.

Play with it and see how you like it. It is relatively poor (according to the above link) for "pathological" URLs, and doesn't work with Arabic etc - but I don't think, based on your question, that this would be an issue.

A short explanation:

```
(?:(?:http|ftp|https):\/{2}){0,1}  

  (?:http|ftp|https)  - match one of http, ftp, or https - non capturing "OR" group
  :\/{2}              - followed by a colon and exactly two forward slashes
  (?: …){0,1}         - the whole thing zero or one times (so no protocol, or properly formed)

(?:(?:[0-9a-z_-]+\.)+ 
   [0-9a-z_-]+\.      - at least one of the characters in the given range, followed by a period
(?:  )+               - the whole thing one or more times, non-capturing

(?:aero|asia …)       - one of these strings, non-capturing (these are all the valid TLDs)
(?::[0-9]+)?          - zero or one times a colon followed by one or more digits: port specification
                      - this makes sure that www.something.us:8080 is valid
```

Everything else that follows matches all the different things that can go after - directories, queries, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look. This looks very impressive from the link you added. I will test on my application. Thanks a lot for the effort @Floris. I appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry, I m not able to vote up because of my reputation. I m fairly new to asking questions here. Once I earn my reputation, I will make sure to vote up.

Comment: Hi Floris - Quick question. This pattern has been very useful for my project, but there is a small issue. It doesn't properly recognize all ftp links. ftp links could be internal too, correct? So, something like [ftp://es-apps.na10.anand/test-ftp-links.txt](ftp://es-apps.na10.anand/test-ftp-links.txt) is not being recognized. Could you please help me with that? Thanks much! (It stops at ftp://es-apps.na1.ar because of the TLD definitions.)

Comment: Hey @AnandRam long time no see. I am not familiar with the link format that you are showing - but if the "TLD equivalent" of the links we are missing is a small number of possible values, you can simply add these other strings to the list `(:?aero|asia|anand|floris)`... etc. If you can't, then use `(:?\w+)` instead of the whole big thing; it will allow "any valid TLD" including ones that would not resolve to a valid URL but are otherwise "legal". Let me know if that solves it for you!

Answer (score 1):

@Floris - Your suggestion worked well. I edited it a little bit and utilized adding a **@** to detect emails as well. I also edited for a simpler workflow as well (without the TLD) -

```
((?:(?:http|ftp|https):\/{2}){0,1}(?:(?:[0-9a-z_@-]+\.)+(?:[0-9a-zA-Z]){2,4})(?::[0-9]+)?(?:(?:\/(?:[~0-9a-zA-Z\#\+\%\@\.\/_-]+))?(?:\?[0-9a-zA-Z\+\%@\/&\[\];=_-]+)?)?)
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You never mentioned you wanted emails… :-) but I'm glad you figure them out by yourself. I think your modified expression will catch a lot of malformed emails though (and you might consider adding a `mailto:` protocol). I agree that not listing all the TLDs is probably a good thing, but as it is your alternative, `(?:[0-9a-zA-Z]){2,4})`, does not match `museum` or `travel` which are valid TLDs… This is a never-ending quest, as you are beginning to discover. But sometimes "good enough" is, indeed, good enough.